# Can't run Admob JAR with another JAR

Tags: android, jar, openfeint

I'm trying to add an external JAR to my project, and i receive this error:

--

```
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lorg/codehaus/jackson/Base64Variant;
[2011-08-24 16:35:19 - MyProjApp] Dx at com.android.dx.dex.file.ClassDefsSection.add(ClassDefsSection.java:123)
[2011-08-24 16:35:19 - MyProjApp] Dx at com.android.dx.dex.file.DexFile.add(DexFile.java:143)
[2011-08-24 16:35:19 - MyProjApp] Dx at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:372)
[2011-08-24 16:35:19 - MyProjApp] Dx at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:346)
[2011-08-24 16:35:19 - MyProjApp] Dx at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$400(Main.java:59)
[2011-08-24 16:35:19 - MyProjApp] Dx at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:294)
[2011-08-24 16:35:19 - MyProjApp] Dx at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:244)
[2011-08-24 16:35:19 - MyProjApp] Dx at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:130)
[2011-08-24 16:35:19 - MyProjApp] Dx at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:108)
[2011-08-24 16:35:19 - MyProjApp] Dx at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:313)
[2011-08-24 16:35:19 - MyProjApp] Dx at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:233)
[2011-08-24 16:35:19 - MyProjApp] Dx at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:185)
[2011-08-24 16:35:19 - MyProjApp] Dx at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor8.invoke(Unknown Source)
[2011-08-24 16:35:19 - MyProjApp] Dx at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
[2011-08-24 16:35:19 - MyProjApp] Dx at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
[2011-08-24 16:35:19 - MyProjApp] Dx at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.DexWrapper.run(DexWrapper.java:179)
[2011-08-24 16:35:19 - MyProjApp] Dx at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.BuildHelper.executeDx(BuildHelper.java:652)
[2011-08-24 16:35:19 - MyProjApp] Dx at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PostCompilerBuilder.build(PostCompilerBuilder.java:510)
[2011-08-24 16:35:19 - MyProjApp] Dx at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:629)
[2011-08-24 16:35:19 - MyProjApp] Dx at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
[2011-08-24 16:35:19 - MyProjApp] Dx at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:172)
[2011-08-24 16:35:19 - MyProjApp] Dx at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:203)
[2011-08-24 16:35:19 - MyProjApp] Dx at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:255)
[2011-08-24 16:35:19 - MyProjApp] Dx at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
[2011-08-24 16:35:19 - MyProjApp] Dx at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:258)
[2011-08-24 16:35:19 - MyProjApp] Dx at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:311)
[2011-08-24 16:35:19 - MyProjApp] Dx at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:343)
[2011-08-24 16:35:19 - MyProjApp] Dx at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:144)
[2011-08-24 16:35:19 - MyProjApp] Dx at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:242)
[2011-08-24 16:35:19 - MyProjApp] Dx at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
[2011-08-24 16:35:19 - MyProjApp] Dx 1 error; aborting
[2011-08-24 16:35:19 - MyProjApp] **Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1**
```

--

I understand that there's a conflict with the jar and a Library project i've added (the Open-Feint library).

My question is if there is something i can do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

I had this exact same problem with the OpenFeint library and I figured it out.

If you are also including the GameFeed project in the

Project > Properties > Android > Library

section, you might be including the OpenFeint API source twice, once in the OpenFeint library and once in the GameFeed project as a dependent library.

I had to delete the OpenFeint API source link from the GameFeed project and then everything worked.

Bottom line is somehow you have the some piece source being built into your project two times.

Answer (score 0):

A not very good solution would be to check that the double class files are the same exact version and if so, delete them from one of the jars...
It's a workaround solution, but not a very safe one... Do it only if you must.

Comment: I though it was because of the two jars, but i've removed the Admob and it still happens.  Its the other company's JAR working with OpenFeint Library Class..

Comment: I have a feeling that you have a copy of the jar file in your src folder... Make sure that you don't have a redundant copy there...

Comment: No i double checked it. i also tried to load it as an external JAR.

Comment: The only thing i CAN see is that the Openfeint Library project does containing the jackson/Base64Variant he is yelling about..